# Persisting the table name in codeigniter models

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model, persist

In my models I'm setting them up using constructors like the following

```
function Areas()
{
    parent::Model();
    $this->db->from("areas");
}
```

However, if a method of my model queries the database several times it looks like the FROM clause is only included in the first query. Is there an easy way to persist the FROM for all queries run within my model (unless I manually override it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against this. It would lead to REALLY hard to smush bugs later on down the line. The problem, I'm guessing, has more to do with the name of the table changing? In which case, you can use a constant for each table and change the name in config.

If you just wanted to save a line of code, sometimes more lines is better. This is the case here.

Comment: What sort of bugs would it lead to?

Comment: Example: You create 4 queries in a row, then add one in the middle that connects to a different table but forget the from. Or remember the from, and forget to add a from to the one after to connect to the other table again. Either bug might prove very hard to trace. Especially if those calls have many lines of code between them. - more over, if they do have many lines between them, you are forced to have to remember what table you are currently locked to.

Comment: But couldn't this go the other way too: if FROM isn't pre-set for all queries, you'd get equivalent bugs for each time you forgot to add the line ->from("table_name"), or had a typo in "table_name"

Comment: Yes, but you'll get those immediately at run time, the first time. And it was the code you just changed. In the other instance, the problem might be in code you wrote a year ago 50 lines above the code you just wrote.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Cheers for coming back to explain. But, as an aside, the reason I thought of implementing this system is that in Zend framework this is pretty much how it works (although admittedly it's probably safer there as you build the queries as separate objects from the actual db connection)

Comment: Correct. Much safer. And if you EVER start doing corn-ball things with your models, such as storing values in members, then calling the model from views. You'll be very happy you bore this in mind.